# pass MYSQL table data into HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a file uploadpostinfo.php,

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $db = "pickeqco_postinfo";
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The $db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
    if (!mysqli_select_db($link, $db)) {
        echo "Database not selected";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, topic, bullet1, bullet2, expl, source FROM postinformation";

    $res = $list->query($sql);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>topic</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["topic"]." ".$row["bullet1"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    //echo nl2br("\n\n$topic\n$bullet1\n$bullet2\n$expl\n$source\n\n");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get values from the database table and insert it into my index.html file. The uploadpostinfo.php and index.html are in the same directory, but are different files.

```
<form action="uploadpostinfo.php" method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="getdata"/>
</form>
```

Can someone please help me get the mysql table data into my html code?

Comment: anything wrong with your current code?

Comment: So, does the PHP-code work? Then try "copy/paste", if you want the PHP-code in another file, or use `include`?

Comment: What happens when you open the uploadpostinfo.php? Is there an error somewhere? If you get no error can you create a php file that dumps phpinfo and make sure it has the correct output? You should set it to display errors. You should look into a templating engine for php as well instead of mixing code with markup.

Comment: @hungrykoala Right now, I don't know if the php file is actually getting the table values since I can't see the table in my html page. In fact, I did not specify that I should create the table in the html page because I do not know how to do so.

Comment: @HMR when I open the uploadpostinfo.php, I have code that shows me if i'm connected to the database. I have successfully connected to MYSQL, but I see no other output other than "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!"

Comment: @Chi `echo "0 results";` is this part of the code working? try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above your code just below `<?php`

Comment: I'm struggling to get the issue. If you want your code on another page, just copy it to that page. The only thing you need to think about is that all pages containing PHP-code need the ".php" extension.

Comment: @hungrykoala I just added your code and it does not output anything

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So should I change my index.html to index.php?

Comment: You can use [Ajax.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to get data from `uploadpostinfo.php` and then render on `index.html`

Comment: uploadpostinfo.php open this file directly and see if any errors are displayed. so thus `echo "0 results"` this part of your code appear?

Comment: @Chi I answered by example code try that in your `index.html`

Comment: @hungrykoala Strangly I can't see that echoed either.

Comment: try to echo anything above your query code if that would display. if possible post your complete code here

Comment: @Chi so is this working `echo "Host information: "`?

Comment: try to do this after `$res = $list->query($sql);`: `var_dump($sql); var_dump($res);` and let us know what they display

Comment: @hungrykoala yes, that part is working, but the echo commands after that are not working at all

Comment: did the var_dump display anything useful?

Comment: **Error reporting**. Try adding this line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your uploadpostinfo.php and try to run it separately to check for errors.

Comment: @hungrykoala still no output in index.html

Comment: run the php file directly and dont mind the html file for now.

Comment: @LoganWayne I have caught no errors

Comment: @Chi - you tried to run uploadpostinfo.php only? And what is `$list` variable? It should be `$link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing result variable but the data is in $res So change

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

to

```
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: thanks, I have changed my code to your suggestion, but unfortunately I still cannot see output in my index.html

Comment: try running the query in phpmyadmin to check if it fetching data ot not.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT id, topic, bullet1, bullet2, expl, source FROM postinformation"; works, but it's not echoing anything.

Comment: have you included the db connection file?

Comment: check your console if it is showing any jquery error? ARe you using jquery?

Comment: I found no errors in the file. I guess I am using jquery since I have it in my head of index.html file

Comment: @Chi _" I guess I am using jquery since I have it in my head"_ - I have to ask, where did you get the code? If you don't even know what the headers are and why they are there, you should start from scratch and read some tutorials about html, javascript and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript code in `index.html`:

```
$.get({
    url: 'uploadpostinfo.php',
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(table){
        $('#yourtableid').html(table);
    }
});
```

Comment: I still can't see any output in the table for some reason.

Comment: @Chi This is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). You have to include a jQuery library for this to work. And @YasharAliasbasi assumes that you add an `id` attribute to your table like `<table id="yourtableid">`

Comment: Is there a way to check if the $sql actually selected the data in php?

Comment: @LoganWayne yes I already have <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in my header

Comment: @Chi try to open `uploadpostinfo.php` directly and inspect objects

Comment: @Chi - check Raman's answer. She pointed out the way you fetch the data. Check her answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code its will help

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",      
        url: uploadpostinfo.php,
        data: dataString,
        complete: function(result){
        $("#showContent").html(result);
    });
```

Comment: still no luck. Do I have to change my table id to 'showContent'?

Comment: you can put anything you want, just need to call in place of showContent